# Why is my foreach is not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am learning asp.net mvc and I am trying to make something like a Yelp....
In a piece of my code I want to iterate through all the categories...
Its starts on number 2: I am having problems in the foreach, its not working...

VStudio tells me that the problem is with the property AverageReviews wich is property of the Place class:

```
public double AverageReviews 
{ get { return (double)SumReviews/(Reviews.Count); } }
```

In my controller I have this:

```
private KekantoContext db = new KekantoContext();

for (int i = 2; i < 8; i++)
{
    var query = db.Places.Where(e => e.Category.CategoryId == i)
        .OrderByDescending(e => e.AverageReviews).Take(3);

    foreach (var aux in query)
    {
        //any code }
    }
}
```

Visual Studio says that Linq to Entities doesnt support my AverageReviews property. But if I change the code and put:  var query = db.Places, my foreach works fine....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to understand, how Linq and EF work together:
EF does not fetch all the entites and then executes the contraints in code, but it translates "everything" to SQL, which it can't do for a property/method which does not exist in your DB.

You can do one of the following:

1) First get all the entities and then execute the ordering "in code":

```
var query = db.Places.Where(e => e.Category.CategoryId == i).ToList()
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.AverageReviews).Take(3);
```

Pay attention to the added `ToList()`.

2) Execute your ordering in a way EF can understand, which is not easy if even possible with your logic, but maybe something like the following works:

```
var query = db.Places.Where(e => e.Category.CategoryId == i).
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.SumReviews/e.Reviews.Count()).Take(3);
```

3) Create a "helper column/table" where you insert the "sort-/order-value" and order after that.

Downside of method one is, that ALL entities matching your `Where()` are loaded and not only 3, method 2 I am not shure if it even works and method 3 would require eighter some DB triggers or manuel update via code, both possibly bad on performance.

Comment: For the second item in your answer .. aren't you worried that SumReviews may be another computed property :)

Answer (score 3):

`AverateReviews` is a computed property so EF cannot generate a store query (sql) based on it.

You could retrieve the data first and then call `ToList()` on it and then order it by AverageReviews.

```
var query = db.Places.Where(e => e.Category.CategoryId == i).Take(3).ToList();

var orderedList = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.AverageReviews).ToList();
```

if you want to order the entire list and take 3 of them .. see below.

```
  var query = db.Places.Where(e => e.Category.CategoryId == i).ToList();

    var orderedList = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.AverageReviews).Take(3).ToList();
```

Comment: I think this would not work, as you always take the same three entities which are first in the DB and then order these three items and not the first three with the highest score...

Comment: @chrfin I just tried to use his own code .. if he wanted to get all the data and order and then take only 3 that should be easy .. probably should modify my answer to reflect that.

Comment: In his code (if it would work) he actually did it in the correct order, but as a beginner he might not get your "functional change" and so you should at least mention it.